# Sorting and grouping a list by order number and created date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am stuck on how to sort a list into a new list with different structure, would if someone could help me with this issue.

Thank you in advance.

List with type

```
public class PartOrders
{
    public string orderNumber{ get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public DateTime performedDateTime { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
}

public class Category 
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The list there are many item with same orderNumber and createdDate

My question is how to make new list with type :

```
public class PartOrders
{
    public string orderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public List<Data> orderDate { get; set; }
} 

public class Data
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime performedDateTime { get; set; }
    public Category category { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate your help

I tried with readinonal way looping with foreach and if condition but it was very complicated and slow.

Result needs to be in this format:

Comment: "Sorting into" sounds weird. That are two different problems and you maybe making your live hard in trying to see them as one? Move your two lists first into a List<RestOfData> and then sort that list.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ralf. I'm thinking about finding a LINQ query by looping throw these two lists and save the result in the new list of type OrderedList

Comment: It looks like List1 model is not related to List2 model,so how do you combine the two model to RestOfData model?

Comment: Hi @Yiyi You , Id and createdDate in both List1 and List2 are the same in the models, so my problem is how to get one id and createdDate in OrderedList and list of common items in as a list in List<RestOfData>, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better change your RestOfData like this,and use `List<RestOfData>` to replace `OrderedList`:

```
 public class RestOfData
{
            public string id { get; set; }
            public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
            public string descriptionA { get; set; }
            public string name{ get; set; }
            public DateTime performedDateTime { get; set; }
            public Gender genderA{ get; set; }
            public string codeData{ get; set; }
            public string descriptionB { get; set; }
            public string orderNumber { get; set; }
            public float total{ get; set; }
            public Gender genderB { get; set; }
}
```

And then use :

```
List<List1> l = ...;
List<List2> l1 = ...;
List<RestOfData> datalist = (from a in l
                          join b in l1 on a.id equals b.id
                          select new RestOfData()
                          {
                              id=a.id,
                              createdDate=a.createdDate,
                              descriptionA=a.descriptionA,
                              name=a.name,
                              performedDateTime=a.performedDateTime,
                              genderA=a.genderA,
                              codeData=b.codeData,
                              descriptionB=b.descriptionB,
                              orderNumber=b.orderNumber,
                              total=b.total,
                              genderB=b.genderB
                          }).OrderBy(xxx).ToList();
```

Comment: Greate Yiyi You :), that solve the half of the problem , final list would be List<orderedData>
class class orderedData
{
            public string id { get; set; }
            public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
            Public List<Data> data { get; set; } 
}
class class Data
{
            public string descriptionA { get; set; }
            public string name{ get; set; }
            .
            .
            .
        
}
where every orderedData item has id , createdDate and list of Data of that has same id and orderedDate.

Comment: You shouldn't use  a list in your `orderedData`.The id should be unique,so there will be only one `Data` for the id,rather than a list for the id.

Comment: Hi Yiyi You, maybe i did not write my question in clear way , i edit the code so could you please take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

it seems your "Lists" are not really lists but data objects or structs.
First thing i would do is to create an interface for both objects that they must implement.
Then you can just

```
List1<ICommonInterface>.Concat(List2<ICommonInterface>).OrderBy(etc..).ThenBy(etc..)
```

both of them.

Comment: Thanks Horst, iam trying to sort List<List1> and List<List2> with items having same id to create new List<OrderedList> with id and createdDate and List<RestOfData>